# arm32v7/ubuntu docker image cannot load so file

Tags: c++, linux, docker, arm, cross-compiling

I am running arm32v7/ubuntu image on my x86 servier with qemu, the environment setup step is roughly like this:

```
## compile qemu static
apt build-dep qemu
git clone --depth 1 git://git.qemu.org/qemu.git
cd qemu
git submodule update --init --recursive 
./configure --prefix=$(cd ..; pwd)/qemu-user-static --static --disable-system --enable-linux-user 
make -j8
make install
```

Then I run the docker image on my x86 server:

```
cd ../qemu-user-static
docker run -v `pwd`/qemu-user-static/bin/qemu-arm-static:/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static -ti arm32v7/ubuntu uname -m
```

The output is `armv7l`.

Then I compile my code on my x86 environment with the arm toolchains compile. The code is like this:

```
// main.cpp
#include "fun.hpp"

int main() {
    print();
}

// fun.hpp
void print();

// fun.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "fun.hpp"

using namespace std;

void print() {
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(example)

include_directories(./)
link_directories(./build)
link_directories(./)

set(toolchain_dir /opt/hisi-linux/x86-arm/arm-himix200-linux)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${toolchain_dir}/bin/arm-himix200-linux-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${toolchain_dir}/bin/arm-himix200-linux-g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=softfp -fPIC -fno-lto -lgomp")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon 7")

set(CMAKE_LINKER "${toolchain_dir}/bin/arm-himix200-linux-ar")
set(CMAKE_AR "${toolchain_dir}/bin/arm-himix200-linux-ar")

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC  -lgomp -fno-lto -O3  -Wall -s")
add_compile_options(-Os -s -fPIC  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections)
add_link_options(-Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--strip-all)


add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main -ltest)

add_library(test SHARED ./fun.cpp)
```

After cross-compiling it on my x86 platform:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

I obtain the `main` and `libtest.so` file. Then I tried to run it within the qemu based `arm32v7/ubuntu` environment. I got the error message:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Also I observed that if I do not use shared memory and compile all code into one single executable file, there will not be problems running it in the arm docker image. What is the problem of this and how could I solve it please ?

Comment: Your `target_link_libraries` looks wrong (you'd usually jut want `test`, not `-ltest`).  `libtest.so` also probably isn't in a default search path for your dynamic loader when you try to run your program through `qemu` (you can probably check with your cross `ldd`).

Comment: @StephenNewell I try both `-ltest` and `test` which makes no difference, and I can run directly on x86 host with `-ltest`. Also, in the docker image, the `ldd` command seems not work well with output of `not a dynamic executable`, though the program can be executable if I do not use shared object.

Comment: @StephenNewell Also I found that, in the arm32v7/gcc docker image, I tried to compile like this: `g++ ../main.cpp -o main -ltest -L./ -Wl,-rpath=./libtest.so` which still does not work and the error message is still: `./main: error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's not how rpath works.  You need to put an absolute path to a folder, not a relative path to a shard library.

Comment: Hi, I tried to compile on arm32v7/gcc with command like this: `++ ../main.cpp  -o main -L`pwd` -ltest -Wl,-rpath=`pwd``, and I run the compiled `main` like this: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./main`, but I still met the same problem. Everything is well if the libtest.so is compiled also in the same docker image, but it will not work if I cross compile it in the x86 platform and link it in the arm docker  image.

Comment: It maybe associated with the toolchain of hisi3516, since I can make it work if I switch the g++ from that provided by the hisi toolchains to the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` installed with ubuntu `apt`. I do not know why it would be like this.